# Labeling when using qgis2web

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, web-mapping, qgis2web

I'm having trouble getting labels to appear in a web map, both Leaflet and OpenLayers, using qgis2web.  I can't get either label buffers or backgrounds to show up and even a Bold style only works in Leaflet (not OL).  And to top it off, the placement, around centroid, only works at higher zoom levels.

Are there ways around this if the qgis2web plugin is deficient?  Maybe modifying the output code (CSS or javascript) after the export?

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to abandon labels (set all layers in QGIS to have no labels (double click on layer in the Layer Panel to open Layer Properties > Labels > No Labels)), and focus on the popups, which are very nice and comparatively easy to deal with for a non-programmer.

I did see there are some Leaflet label plugins (though am not finding them now), but did not investigate them.